# Regular Expression need to escape < br>

Tags: regular-expressions, line-break

I'm using the following regular expression: `(https?://(?i)www.|https?|www.)([A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+[.][A-Za-z]{2,3}`

but for urls such as for instance: `http://www.url1.com<br>http://www.url2.com`

the regular expression is not working.

What is the regular expression to help me escape and ignore the `<br>` between the urls?

Comment: Just spilt Urls based on "<br>" and then check for url.

Comment: I've tried with .split('<br>') but it is not working.

Comment: Try to execute below answer in  anonymous window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example using String.spilt() function.

```
String url3='http://www.url1.com<br>http://www.url2.com<br>abcd://asdasd.tt<br>http://google.com<br>http://11asds.co.in<br>https:///google.com<br>http://_fsds.co<br>https://google<br>http://google.';

String urlRegex = '^((http|https)://)??(www[.])??([a-zA-Z0-9]|-)+?([.][a-zA-Z0-9(-|/|=|?)??]+?)+?$';
    Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex);
String[] str = url3.split('<br>');
for(String s:str) {    
    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(s);
    system.debug('#####valid url :'+ MyMatcher.matches() );    
}
```

[image]